# Arduino code not running when getting pre-determined string from python on serial

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

I am trying to have my arduino uno run when code is sent to it, however, nothing happens except the lights blinking back and forth for a second when it is sent and then nothing. I am just sending a string on serial, and using an if statement so it should be super straight forward but I am not sure what is happening to cause it not to work. Code below, any help would be awesome.
Python

```py
import serial, time
arduino = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=1)
cmd = ''
while cmd != '0':
        cmd = input('Enter a cmd ')
        arduino.write(cmd.encode('ascii'))
```

Arduino

```cpp
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    delay(100);
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    String stringFromSerial = Serial.readString();
    if (stringFromSerial == "1") {
        Serial.println("1");

    } else if (stringFromSerial == "2") {
        Serial.println("2");

    } else if (stringFromSerial == "3") {
        Serial.println("3");

    } else {
        Serial.println("Not recognized cmd");

    }
  }
}
```

Update: Thanks for the help, I have updated the code to what actually works.

Comment: Please learn the basic [str methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) and understand what the `str.encode()` do.

Comment: I would recommend creating a new sketch from scratch, where you don't add any motors or anything. In this sketch you just read the serial port for a single character 'a' or 'b' and turn the built-in led on or off. Once you get this working try sending a whole word like 'on' or 'off'. You can make the arduino ping back what you send, so you can see if there's any difference (eg: added newlines, etc..) Finally you might want to add a time.sleep() in your python code after the command has been send, otherwise python will automatically close the port. Try this and forget about motors for now.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki I will do this and get back to you

Comment: A string `fwd\r\n` is not equal to a string `fwd`. This [readstring example](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/readstring/) shows how to read string and also shows how to compare two strings (read the comment of the code).

Comment: @hcheung If i wanted to just send 1, 2, or 3 and have an if statement, what would the code look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated by hcheung, the string you want to send isn't correct.

Looking at the [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_encode.asp) and [programiz](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/encode), I suggest you do something similar to

```
cmd = 'fwd'
arduino.write(cmd.encode('ascii'))
```

Or, for non-ASCII character commands, you can encode as 'UTF-8'.  But I doubt you'd be happy with those encodings.

```
arduino.write(cmd.encode(encoding='UTF-8'))
```

You could also send multiple commands from Python like so:

```
in = ''
while in != '0':
    in = input('Enter a command: ')
    arduino.write(in.encode('ascii'))
    # this loop will exit if you enter '0',
    # but will first send the exit command to the Arduino
```

and receive multiple commands on the Arduino side:

```
void loop() {
    delay(100);
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    String stringFromSerial = Serial.readString();
    if (stringFromSerial == "1") {
        // do something for command 1

    } else if (stringFromSerial == "2") {
        // do something for command 2

    } else if (stringFromSerial == "3") {
        // do something for command 3

    } else {
        // do an exit command perhaps

    }
}
```

Comment: If i wanted to just send 1, 2, or 3 and have an if statement, what would the code look like?

Comment: @Garberchov  Updated with more elaborate example.

Comment: I apologize for the late response, I have done this with my Arduino code and have it set to print to the serial monitor whenever it receives the commands however I am struggling to test this as I can't have the serial monitor open while sending from the python file, and I can't use the onboard lights as they run whenever a serial command is recieved. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @Garberchov I'd recommend using the onboard LED _anyway._ If you receive a command, then wait one or two seconds, then do one, two, or three short blinks on the internal LED (or any number of blinks that you can distinguish) you have a simple debugging tool.